# Recursive Way to Find & Assign Correct Value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a situation where I need to find a value from an array of objects, depending on the object that has the highest value for a property named `sequence`. When I find the object with the highest numeric value for `sequence` then I want to assign the value of variable to the value of another property on that same object. I could do this with a long loop with numerous conditionals, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to do this via some kind of recursive process.

My data look like this:

```
let endDate;

let data = [
  {
    clientId: 912,
    coverage: {
      start: '2021-07-30',
      finish: '2021-12-31',
      agent: {
        name: 'Second',
        sequence: 2
      },
    }
  },
    {
    clientId: 912,
    coverage: {
      start: '2021-08-01',
      finish: '2021-12-20',
      agent: {
        name: 'First',
        sequence: 1
      },
    }
  },
    {
    clientId: 912,
    coverage: {
      start: '2021-09-13',
      finish: '2021-12-25',
      agent: {
        name: 'Third',
        sequence: 3
      },
    }
  },
];
```

What I want do do is set a variable named `subscriptionEndDate` to the value of `finish` on whatever object from the above array that has the highest numeric value for `coverage.agent.sequence`.

The result for `endDate` for the above data should be `'2021-12-25'`.

Comment: pliease highlight the recursive part. what have you done?

Comment: There will be an unknown number of objects in the array. I need to look through all of the objects, find the highest numeric value for `coverage.agent.sequence`, and then assign the value of `finish` on that object to my variable `endDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need recursion as you'll only need to iterate over the array and get the client with max sequence, you can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as follows:

```js
const data = [
  { clientId: 912, coverage: { id: 59307, start: '2021-07-30', finish: '2021-12-31', agent: { name: 'Third', sequence: 2 } } },
  { clientId: 912, coverage: { id: 59307, start: '2021-08-01', finish: '2021-12-20', agent: { name: 'First', sequence: 1 } } },
  { clientId: 912, coverage: { start: '2021-09-13', finish: '2021-12-25', agent: { name: 'Second', sequence: 3 } } }
];

const clientWithHighestSequence = data.reduce((maxSeqClient, client) => 
  client.coverage.agent.sequence > (maxSeqClient?.coverage.agent.sequence ?? 0)
    ? client
    : maxSeqClient
, null);

console.log(clientWithHighestSequence);
```

Comment: why a start value and necessary (superfluous) checks?

Comment: What would the start value be other than ``null``? consider empty arrays as well..

Comment: check the array in advance and return some value for empty array.